# Identifying CMS

Tags: php, web, twitter-bootstrap-3, content-management-system

Ive spent a fair amount of time trying to work this one out, to no avail.
Basically, I'm looking to identify what CMS a previous developer has been using with a client I have just taken on. It only administers half of their website, and in order to go forward with the project, I would like to know what it's utilising.

I have reverse image searched the logo and found a couple of sites using the same system, so I know it's not a bespoke system however I can't find any clues in the code or on BuiltWith etc.

I almost feel i recognise it, but can't put my finger on it. The logo is a blue, 3D cube and it makes use of Bootstrap.

I have found what looks to be the same system running on booter.io and booter.in, along with elitephysics.in. I have attached a few screenshots, including a blanked one from my clients login page.

Any help on this would be much appreciated in order for me to move forwards with my project.

--Seems I cannot post images due to low rep, so heres a imgur gallery containing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGMLa.jpg

Thanks guys!

Comment: Is this for a company? Don't they have all the base code or documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think they had a fall out with their previous developer as they don't seem willing to talk with them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research all I found is that the design is from a Bootstrap's theme and not a CMS

Not sure if it will help you

Here is a link to the theme : https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/clean-zone-responsive-admin-template-WB00XNXM0

Comment: Thank you. I knew i'd seen it somewhere before...

Comment: I wonder why my answer is getting -1 even if the problem is solved... Anyone can help me to figure why ?

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at any of the source files - if you have access to the PHP files for the CMS these often contain copyright notices including the developer names

Comment: Can't see any. Have had a rummage through the sources and can't find a single copyright, or name left behind. Seems really strange.
I also can't seem to work out how one of the pages is even invoking the information it's pulling from the DB as there seems to be no include of a php file or anything.